# is it possible to run pygame or pyglet in a browser?

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.7, pyglet, activepython

I have 3 game libraries installed on my PC: pyglet, pygame and Panda3D.

I would like to create a 2D game and make it a web browser game so i can put it on facebook.

I know that [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/) has a web-browser-plugin.  Panda3D is for 3D games **mainly**.

Therefore, I'm asking, is it possible to play a [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) or [pygame](http://pygame.org/news.html) game in a browser? If not, what Python library do you recommend?

Comment: Not sure about pyglet or pygame. Probably not. But you might want to check out (http://pyjs.org/)

Comment: e.g.: [replit.com](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateAroundPivot#main.py)

Comment: both pygame and Panda3D can now run in the browser for pygame see https://github.com/pygame-web ( demo  pmp-p.github.io/pygame-wasm/  ) and for panda3d see https://rdb.name/panda3d-webgl.md.html ( demo https://rdb.name/panda3d-webgl/editor.html )

Answer (score 11):

Neither pyglet nor pygame will run in a browser. I wouldn't really recommend using Python at all if you target is a web browser. JavaScript (with HTML5 Canvas), <strike>Flash, or Java applets are</strike> is better suited for that environment.

If you're dedicated to the idea of using Python, there are a number of projects that can compile Python into JavaScript. There are [some mentioned on the Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming). Here are a few:

- [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/)
- Pyjamas
- Pyjaco

You'll need to write your own graphics and audio systems, though, since none of those projects can convert the native code needed by pyglet and pygame into JavaScript.

Comment: Ah, you might be interested in Jython, then. I didn't think about it yesterday. A search for "jython applets" will lead you to some information on the subject.

Comment: the goal is running in the browser, not running python in javascript. There are efficient alternative to javascript in order run cpython in the browser : like asm.js or webassembly ( which is now supported officialy by cpython )

Comment: this was a great answer and, 10 years later, still true... javascript is naturally for the browser, Python is not the natural choice.

Comment: @D.L The question is not about natural choice or your personnal feelings about javascript. The question is running Python ( the interpreter) + pygame + SDL1 or 2 and rendering a 2D game ( that means with graphic at 60FPS, multitouch+gamepad and proper sounds yes that include WAV and MP3 ) not some half baked js solution that will never get it 100% right and cannot decode half the codecs around.  btw i'm a pygame-ce maintener and i think i've tried all available solutions around and none would fit until asm.js/WASM came.

Comment: @PmpP. instead of having a go at people, suggest an answer. I can achieve this is javascript, but not in python. So if you have an answer then post it. I would be interested and really pleased to see a good answer / solution...

Comment: well i guess you did not see  that the answer is there since the 6 august 2022, use pygbag the wasm packaging from pygame-web the endorsed project from pygame-ce . sorry for the harsh comment then and go enjoy some games here https://itch.io/c/2563651/pygame-wasm

Comment: and now pyglet is half supported if someone really need it

Comment: Skulpt link doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

Today, i'd recommand using pygbag https://pypi.org/project/pygbag/ from https://pygame-web.github.io. It uses the same principles from Panda3D webgl port ( not the old plugin) using Web Assembly for modern browsers.

-- edit 22 nov 2023 --

installation is simple : pip3 install pygbag

using it : python3 -m pygbag your_game_folder/main.py

with pygbag tool you can host/run/package directly your pygame-ce/panda3D desktop project in all modern browsers ( and Safari iOS>=15 )

it is already widely adopted for 2D game jams https://itch.io/c/2563651/pygame-wasm  and you can also start 3D projects https://itch.io/c/3724091/panda3d-wasm

You can also use pygame-ce wasm in REPLit with pygbag to get a performance gain ( people using it said it makes a big difference ) for that see https://github.com/pygame-web/pygbag/issues/110

Answer (score 4):

It requires a bit of reprogramming, but i made a pygame library "port" to the browser/nodewebkit using Brython and GameJS. You can program using a version of pygame and python 3 in the browser. You can check it out at https://github.com/asherwunk/pygjs

Answer (score 3):

An option is to use [repl.it](https://repl.it). It allows creating Python/PyGame scripts and multiplayer coding. When creating a new *repl*, select the Pygame template:

[image]

---

Example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TransparentShapes](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TransparentShapes#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option to run pygame in a browser is to use [pygbag](https://pygame-web.github.io/). Install pygbag with [`pip install pygbag`](https://pypi.org/project/pygbag/)

```
pip install pygbag
```

Put the code in a file named ***main.py*** and adapt your pygame code like this:

```py
import pygame
import asyncio

pygame.init()

# initializations: pygame.display.set_mode, ...
# [...]

def main():

    run = True
    while run:

        # application loop: pygame.event.get(), pygame.display.flip(), ...
        # [...]

        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        
asyncio.run(main())
```

Build the project with the command:

```
pygbag .
```

---

Minimal example:

[Live demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/examples/minimal_exmaples_web/pygame_minimal_move_object/build/web/)

```py
import pygame
import asyncio

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
rect.center = window.get_rect().center
vel = 5

async def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                print(pygame.key.name(event.key))

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * vel
        rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * vel
            
        rect.centerx = rect.centerx % window.get_width()
        rect.centery = rect.centery % window.get_height()

        window.fill(0)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, "red", rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

    pygame.quit()
    exit()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: wouldn't main be async in your 2nd codeblock

Answer (score -1):

I just found this website https://trinket.io/features/pygame that allows you to run pygame from this website! But it's extremely slow. It should work from your browser but it'll take forever to run it.