# What languages are used for programming browser games

Tags: javascript, python, flash, browser, pygame

Is it neccessary to learn Adobe Flash to program browser games? And does it cost money to use and program in Flash? Another question I have and it's about Python and pygame. Can I program a game in Python and pygame that runs in a browser? Or is JavaScript the best and easiest way to go from a programmers and users stand point?

Comment: The use of the Canvas and HTML5 provides for nice ways to create games in a browser. You can't directly run Python in a browser - there is some conversion-to-JavaScript tool, but I'm not sure how supported it is. I would stay away from Flash...http://isflashdeadyet.com/

Comment: You can't program a browser based game in python yet. Here's an extensive list of HTML5 game engines/frameworks https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you may use.

**Java**, can be embedded in browsers using applets, and are used in many browser games.

There is a Unity game engine that is cross platform, but needs Unity Player for web platform. As you mentioned Flash has the same approach.

The only advantage of flash is that more than 95 percent of desktop devices have flash support, in the pre-HTML5 era of the web, we needed some dynamism. But if you go for flash, you will miss the mobile market.

IF you want your game to be truly cross-browser, JavaScript is the way to go. Performance was the main question in mind but, modern browsers are always trying to excel at Javascript performance. For example, Mozilla guys recently imported Unreal3 Game engine to Firefox, using their shiny technology "Emscripten". See demo here [Mozilla And Epic Games Bring Unreal Engine 3 To The Web, No Plugin Needed](http://bgr.com/2013/05/03/mozilla-firefox-unreal-engine-3-port/).

So my final answer is JavaScript. Use JavaScript and you will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, and I believe it costs money(not sure).

2) [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452927/is-it-possible-to-run-pygame-or-pyglet-in-a-browser)

3) Use what you like to use, whether that be python or javascript. Also, if you choose javascript just use html 5 and javascript with a html5 canvas.

You can code games any of those way, I haven't used flash so I couldn't give you advice, but I believe that it is much easier and productive to just go with what you know, but if you haven't been hacking in python or javascript for years I would learn javascript, but it is somewhat of a personal prefrence, but it is much easier in javascript IMHO. It took me and a few friends multiple months just to get a 2d game map wasd controls, but took us less time in java to make a 3d physics engine. Also, going forward less tablets and the other emerging markets are not going to support Flash, besides it being what you know.