# How to redirect wsl2 display to local windows machine in python

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x11

I have a python game that is being run on wl2 and I would like the display to be in windows. I have tried to use the code below in my python program but it just gets stuck because it is not the correct display. I have also checked out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680740/x11-forwarding-from-wsl2-to-remote-machine) but it did not seem to be an answer I could apply to this project. I could just run this program in windows but that causes a whole lot of other problems and will probably have to be in another question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I wish I could share the program but unfortunately it's for a ctf and should not be posted :(

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479978/pygame-display-init-error-no-available-video-device-on-vps-server) question for reference to the code below:

```py
import os
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
```

Without the above code:
[image]

With the above code (seems to be working but nothing shows up):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Audio**

You can not redirect audio (ALSA) with WSL2. You could still try something *streaming with ffmpeg from linux to windows*.

**Graphics**

Setup an X server on your windows host and provide a DISPLAY environment variable on WSL to it, e.g.

```
DISPLAY=172.24.144.1:0
```

On WSL2 `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` unfortunately does not work, so you have to check your machine adapter addresses on Windows side.

There are plenty of them. I used very simple (and handy) **Xming X Server for Windows** aka XLaunch.

This one is compatible with **opengl** X11 drivers.

**UPDATE**

You can nicely automate setting properly `DISPLAY` variable by adding this line to the `~/.bashrc` file in your WSL2 machine:

```bash
export DISPLAY=`grep -oP "(?<=nameserver ).+" /etc/resolv.conf`:0.0
```