# Python GUI to web based application

Tags: python

Can I make a GUI based python application into a web based application?
I am making a game in python using pygame and want it to be a web based game, will it be possible or not.

Comment: Need more info. Which libs do you use? How your GUI app is built?

Comment: Neither pyglet nor pygame will run in a browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452927/is-it-possible-to-run-pygame-or-pyglet-in-a-browser

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. It is possible with some limitations to compile games made in PyGame into JavaScript using PyJS compiler bundled with [PyJSDL](https://gatc.ca/projects/pyjsdl/). It works, there's simple demo on their webpage but it only supports a [subset](https://gatc.ca/projects/pyjsdl/doc/) of PyGame features.

I wouldn't recommend to use it if you are not strong in Python and debugging it.