# Python and Flask - Web Game with pygames or other options

Tags: python, html, web, web-applications

I have been assessed at uni to develop a web app using Python and Flask and I thought about developing a browser game. My ideas as of now would be to either, develop a fighting game like classic Street Fighter or an adventure game like classic Zelda. I've seen some recommendations as well of using `pygames` or `pyjs` as a **backend**, but I don't really understand what that means. I'm fairly new to Python and Flask and those are the tools that I definitely have to use. I have a virtual machine provided by the university that will act as a server for hosting the website, it runs Ubuntu.

The idea can change with no problem, I read as well that a text based game, like a visual novel, would be easier to develop, but I really wanted to push myself and try something more. My teacher recommended ***building a small game engine in python and exposing it as a text game via Flask.***

Any help would be appreciated, just need some opinions regarding this. What do you think, is it doable?

(not quite sure about the tags, sorry if they are wrong or messy)

Comment: You cannot use pygame in an web environment. See [is it possible to run pygame or pyglet in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452927/is-it-possible-to-run-pygame-or-pyglet-in-a-browser)

Comment: Are there any other python libraries that I could use or should I just discard it and use JavaScript instead?

Comment: Depending on your needs use https://p5js.org/ or https://threejs.org/

Comment: I’ll give them a look, thank you very much.