# Pygame window not opening, no error messages

Tags: python, pygame, window

I'm trying to create a simple game using Pygame, but the game window is not opening. I'm not seeing any error messages related to Pygame itself. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import pygame as py

#initialize only the display module
py.display.init()

#screen
screen = py.display.set_mode((800,600))

#title
py.display.set_caption("Shooter")

#icon
icon = py.image.load("maths.png")
py.display.set_icon(icon)
icon2 = py.image.load("maths.png")

#player
playerx = 400
playery = 300

def main():
    screen.blit(icon2, (playerx, playery))

#gameloop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((252,0,0))
    main()
    py.display.update()
    for event in py.event.get():
            if event.type == py.QUIT:
                running = False
```

When i run the script,I see the following message, meaning that my code is running:
"pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.2, Python 3.10.13)
Hello from the pygame community. [https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html"](https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html%22)

I've tried the following things to troubleshoot this issue:

Checked that Pygame is properly installed
Tried running the script directly from the terminal
Checked for other Pygame windows
Tried running a minimal Pygame script
Checked my system's task manager
Tried running the script in a new Python environment
Reinstalled Python and Pygame
Looked at similar problems and solution on stack overflow
None of these have helped. I'm running Python 3.10.13 and Pygame 2.5.2 on VS Code through Github.dev on windows 11. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have implemented your suggestion but unfortunately the same problem persists.

Comment: *When i run the script,I see the following message, meaning that my code is running*  where do you see this message?

Comment: I see it in the terminal

Comment: I have tried to run it on VS Code and it ends up working. although this is a solution, I would like to find the problem coming from the Github version as i prefer working directly from there.

Comment: I'm not sure if you would be able to launch pygame window using github.dev, since that is browser based, and pygame needs access to your system tools to launch the window.

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452927/is-it-possible-to-run-pygame-or-pyglet-in-a-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452927/is-it-possible-to-run-pygame-or-pyglet-in-a-browser)